# How to get wine to recognize dll files?

Tags: linux, qt, dll, windows-7, wine

I am trying to get wine to run an exe file of a program that I wrote in windows. Whenever it executes the program, it comes back with a bunch of missing dll files. The problem is that when opening a dll, wine shows all the dll files that are missing for it to run, but then proceeds to open the next dll that it just previously said was missing.

To illustrate my point here is an analogy:

- `Peanutbutter.dll` (which is needed by Sandwich.dll) not found
- `Knife.dll` (which is needed by Peanutbutter.dll) not found

It just said it couldn't find the peanut butter, but then proceeds to find it and tell me what the peanutbutter is missing. Everything is in the same folder and it can clearly find them, so why aren't they linking?

Here is the exact error code that I am getting:

```
tester@LubuntuTester:~$ wine /home/tester/Desktop/release/GUI-1.exe
err:module:import_dll Library MSVCP140.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\tester\\Desktop\\release\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\tester\\Desktop\\release\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\tester\\Desktop\\release\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\tester\\Desktop\\release\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\tester\\Desktop\\release\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\tester\\Desktop\\release\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\tester\\Desktop\\release\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\tester\\Desktop\\release\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\tester\\Desktop\\release\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\tester\\Desktop\\release\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\tester\\Desktop\\release\\Qt5Core.dll") not found
.
.
.
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\\home\\tester\\Desktop\\release\\GUI-1.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

This is for a Qt gui program that I wrote in windows and am trying to get running in Linux. The problem with the linuxdeployqt tool is that it is for 64bit operating systems and my device has a 32bit processor. My solution is to just use the deployed exe from windows on Linux using wine, but I get the above errors.